# Redirect all .com (non www and www) to .co.uk

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I can't seem to find the syntax for redirecting all non-www and www of .com domains to the .co.uk domain. I can find the .co.uk to .com but not this way around.

What is the htaccess snippet to do this?

e.g

```
www.domain.com redirects to www.domain.co.uk
```

and

```
domain.com redirects to www.domain.co.uk
```

Comment: If you have a redirect for .co.uk to .com reversing it should be trivial. What have you tried?

Comment: I think this belongs on http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.domain.co.uk/$1  [L,R=301]
```